# Mongoose search for similarities between array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have a collection with a property of weekdays (sunday, monday, thuesday).
When searching for object on the client, I want to send an array of days ['sunday', 'friday']
and get all the objects that have either sunday or friday.
Is there an operator for that or should this be built from scratch?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you add an example of your document schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$in` operator:

```
db.collection.find({ weekdays: { $in: ['sunday', 'friday'] }})
```